# docker failed to create endpoint xxx on network br1: network xxx does not exist

Tags: docker, docker-network

when i created the network,it can work properly.

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker run --net=br1 --ip=192.168.0.119 -ti --name=doc 328edcd84f1b /bin/bash
[root@8f5c0179d86a /]# ping www.baidu.com
PING www.a.shifen.com (115.239.210.27) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 115.239.210.27 (115.239.210.27): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=10.8 ms
```

but when i reboot the host(or restart the docker),it failed to start containers

I display the list of networks, it is there,but the error message tells me that it does not exist

my docker version is 1.12.6

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
e83fa9afc6af        br1                 bridge              local               
2fb7bed3e5ba        bridge              bridge              local               
984a5e65f182        host                host                local               
d8e8ce860225        none                null                local               
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# docker network inspect br1
[
    {
        "Name": "br1",
        "Id": "e83fa9afc6af2cf01b0b0103d0c98d7334717cdd5290e2121dc03a5d6b48aa84",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.0.0/24",
                    "IPRange": "192.168.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.0.120"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "br0",
            "parent": "ens33"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
[root@localhost ~]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
8f5c0179d86a        328edcd84f1b        "/bin/bash"         2 hours ago         Exited (137) 56 minutes ago                       doc
2492467008a0        328edcd84f1b        "/bin/bash"         2 hours ago         Exited (127) 2 hours ago                          mytest1
a3c7184a4bf5        328edcd84f1b        "/bin/bash"         17 hours ago        Exited (0) 17 hours ago                           awesome_perlman
f1e26864c870        328edcd84f1b        "/bin/bash"         18 hours ago        Exited (128) 17 hours ago                         berserk_kalam
ce2d1b7a6ce2        328edcd84f1b        "/bin/bash"         18 hours ago        Exited (1) 2 hours ago                            lonely_banach
[root@localhost ~]# docker start doc
Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint doc on network br1: network e83fa9afc6af2cf01b0b0103d0c98d7334717cdd5290e2121dc03a5d6b48aa84 does not exist
Error: failed to start containers: doc
```

Comment: You are on a decently old version of docker. Please updated to the latest `17.06` one and see if the issue is still there. Also if it is the there then stop docker service using `systemctl stop docker` and then do `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker`. This gets rid of of all your images, containers etc. Start docker again and see if the things work fine now. This you can try even before upgrading. But do remember all images, network, volumes, everything would get deleted

Comment: i have updated to 17.06，there is no problem now .  thanks